# Google Cloud Functions alert based in Logs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I went through the docs but I couldn't find a way of sending an alert based on my Cloud function logs, is this possible?

What I want to do is trigger an alert when I get an specific log node.

Like, every time I have this:
[image]

Triggers an alert in my GCP, is that possible?

Comment: What do you want to do? Send an email (or SLACK or other type of email), or do you want to post a PubSub message to process the load automatically (in a Cloud Function for example)?

Comment: Mon Ami! Thank you for your comment! I want exactly what @Mahboob answered, just an alert in GPC when I have an specific log in my logs. But is great to know that I can automatize with pub sub! Can you send me docs or tell me about it? For exemple if my my VM is shut down can I activate a cloud function to restart it? Merci!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an [log-based metric](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics#logs-based_metrics_interface) from the advanced filter of the Logs and create an alerting from the log-based metric. To create alert from the log-based metric you need to click on three dot right side of the metric name there you will see the [create alert](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/charts-and-alerts) option.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to log-based metrics, now [log-based](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/alerting/log-based-alerts) alerts are also supported. This lets you receive notification whenever a specific message appears in logs.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I'll try that too!